# How to set viewBox attribute for svg using 'use' tag?

Tags: html, svg

..

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <symbol id="svg-rating-star">
      <!-- svg content -->
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>

<span>case 1:</span>
<svg class="svg-rating-star" width="50" height="10" viewBox="10 0 50 10">
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star"></use>
</svg>
<svg class="svg-rating-star" width="50" height="10" viewBox="20 0 50 10">
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star"></use>
</svg>

<span>case 2:</span>
<svg class="svg-rating-star" width="50" height="10" viewBox="10 0 50 10">
  <!-- svg content -->
</svg>
<svg class="svg-rating-star" width="50" height="10" viewBox="20 0 50 10">
  <!-- svg content -->
</svg>
```

more specific in [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nwqe26u3/)

in case 1, svg's viewBox is not working as i expected. its viewport does move but the rest stars are not shown.

if the svg's content is set within it like case 2, it works perfectly.

how to set viewBox for the svgs in case 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're having is because the `width` value of a `<use>` element defaults to `"100%"` if it is not specified.  In this case that means `"50"` because that's what's specified on the two `<svg>` elements.

Because it is only 50, that means that only the five gold stars will ever be shown.  Even when you change the viewBox, you are only just shifting those five gold stars left.

The solution is to specify a `width="100"` on your `<use>` elements so that all the stars are made visible.

```css
.svg-rating-star .svg-rating-star-active {
  fill: #fdcc00;
}
.svg-rating-star .svg-rating-star-inactive {
  fill: #d1d1d1;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="svg-rating-star" class="svg-rating-star">
      <g id="svg-rating-star_svg-rating-star">
        <polygon class="svg-rating-star-active" points="4.732,0 6.194,2.963 9.463,3.438 7.098,5.745 7.656,9 4.732,7.463 1.807,9 2.366,5.745 0,3.438 3.269,2.963 "></polygon>
        <polygon class="svg-rating-star-active" points="14.732,0 16.194,2.963 19.463,3.438 17.098,5.745 17.656,9 14.732,7.463 11.807,9 12.366,5.745 10,3.438 13.269,2.963 "></polygon>
        <polygon class="svg-rating-star-active" points="24.732,0 26.194,2.963 29.463,3.438 27.098,5.745 27.656,9 24.732,7.463 21.807,9 22.365,5.745 20,3.438 23.27,2.963 "></polygon>
        <polygon class="svg-rating-star-active" points="34.732,0 36.194,2.963 39.463,3.438 37.098,5.745 37.656,9 34.732,7.463 31.807,9 32.365,5.745 30,3.438 33.27,2.963 "></polygon>
        <polygon class="svg-rating-star-active" points="44.732,0 46.194,2.963 49.463,3.438 47.098,5.745 47.656,9 44.732,7.463 41.807,9 42.365,5.745 40,3.438 43.27,2.963 "></polygon>
        <polygon class="svg-rating-star-inactive" points="54.732,0 56.194,2.963 59.463,3.438 57.098,5.745 57.656,9 54.732,7.463 51.807,9 52.365,5.745 50,3.438 53.27,2.963 "></polygon>
        <polygon class="svg-rating-star-inactive" points="64.732,0 66.194,2.963 69.463,3.438 67.098,5.745 67.656,9 64.732,7.463 61.807,9 62.365,5.745 60,3.438 63.27,2.963 "></polygon>
        <polygon class="svg-rating-star-inactive" points="74.732,0 76.194,2.963 79.463,3.438 77.098,5.745 77.656,9 74.732,7.463 71.807,9 72.365,5.745 70,3.438 73.27,2.963 "></polygon>
        <polygon class="svg-rating-star-inactive" points="84.732,0 86.194,2.963 89.463,3.438 87.098,5.745 87.656,9 84.732,7.463 81.807,9 82.365,5.745 80,3.438 83.27,2.963 "></polygon>
        <polygon class="svg-rating-star-inactive" points="94.732,0 96.194,2.963 99.463,3.438 97.098,5.745 97.656,9 94.732,7.462 91.807,9 92.365,5.745 90,3.438 93.27,2.963 "></polygon>
      </g>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg class="svg-rating-star" width="50" height="10" viewBox="10 0 50 10">
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" width="100"/>
</svg>
<br/>
<svg class="svg-rating-star" width="50" height="10" viewBox="20 0 50 10">
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" width="100"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that the only one way here is to duplicate one path to different id's:

```css
.svg-rating-star-inactive {
  fill: #d1d1d1;
}

.svg-rating-star-active {
  fill: #fdcc00;
}
```

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="display: none">
      <defs>
        <symbol id="svg-rating-star">
          <polygon points="4.732,0 6.194,2.963 9.463,3.438 7.098,5.745 7.656,9 4.732,7.463 1.807,9 2.366,5.745 0,3.438 3.269,2.963 "></polygon>
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="svg-rating-star0">
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="0" class="svg-rating-star-inactive"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="10" class="svg-rating-star-inactive"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="20" class="svg-rating-star-inactive"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="30" class="svg-rating-star-inactive"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="40" class="svg-rating-star-inactive"></use>
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="svg-rating-star1">
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="0" class="svg-rating-star-active"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="10" class="svg-rating-star-inactive"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="20" class="svg-rating-star-inactive"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="30" class="svg-rating-star-inactive"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="40" class="svg-rating-star-inactive"></use>
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="svg-rating-star2">
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="0" class="svg-rating-star-active"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="10" class="svg-rating-star-active"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="20" class="svg-rating-star-inactive"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="30" class="svg-rating-star-inactive"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="40" class="svg-rating-star-inactive"></use>
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="svg-rating-star3">
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="0" class="svg-rating-star-active"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="10" class="svg-rating-star-active"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="20" class="svg-rating-star-active"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="30" class="svg-rating-star-inactive"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="40" class="svg-rating-star-inactive"></use>
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="svg-rating-star4">
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="0" class="svg-rating-star-active"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="10" class="svg-rating-star-active"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="20" class="svg-rating-star-active"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="30" class="svg-rating-star-active"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="40" class="svg-rating-star-inactive"></use>
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="svg-rating-star5">
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="0" class="svg-rating-star-active"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="10" class="svg-rating-star-active"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="20" class="svg-rating-star-active"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="30" class="svg-rating-star-active"></use>
          <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star" x="40" class="svg-rating-star-active"></use>
        </symbol>
      </defs>
    </svg>
    <br/>
    <svg width="50" height="10" viewBox="0 0 50 10">
      <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star0"></use>
    </svg>
    <br/>
    <svg width="50" height="10" viewBox="0 0 50 10">
      <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star1"></use>
    </svg>
    <br/>
    <svg width="50" height="10" viewBox="0 0 50 10">
      <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star2"></use>
    </svg>
    <br/>
    <svg width="50" height="10" viewBox="0 0 50 10">
      <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star3"></use>
    </svg>
    <br/>
    <svg width="50" height="10" viewBox="0 0 50 10">
      <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star4"></use>
    </svg>
    <br/>
    <svg width="50" height="10" viewBox="0 0 50 10">
      <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-rating-star5"></use>
    </svg>
```